# Mixed content warning as a result of taglib URI

Tags: https, tiles, struts2-jquery

I am getting Mixed content warning in IE 11.
My page uses struts2 with various tag libs and Apache tiles.
I am unable so far to understand what resource is causing this warning - Fiddler does not show anything.

My question is : is it possible that taglib uris in jsp page can cause mixed content warning: 
"<%@ taglib uri="http://tiles.apache.org/tags-tiles" prefix="tiles" %>"

The uri is http while the page is opened in https.

Thank you.

Kirill.

Update :

The reason was indeed a tag but the one generating Jvascript code for the client:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason was the following s:url tag:

```
 <s:url id="contextroot" includeContext="true"  forceAddSchemeHostAndPort="true"  value=""/>
```

This tag was used to access JQuery theme in the next one:

```
<sj:head jqueryui="true" jquerytheme="cupertino" customBasepath="%{contextroot}themes" locale="en" />
```

This generated the following HTML in the client page:

```
<link id="jquery_theme_link" rel="stylesheet" href="http://xxx.xxx.xxx.com/reportcenter/themes/cupertino/jquery-ui.css?s2j=3.6.1" type="text/css"/>
```

Which had http since the application server is running in http.

The solution was to remove forceAddSchemeHostAndPort="true".
This way the path is generated relatively :

```
<link id="jquery_theme_link" rel="stylesheet" href="themes/cupertino/jquery-ui.css?s2j=3.6.1" type="text/css"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ieinternals/2009/06/22/handling-mixed-httpshttps-content/

According to this you are probably correct. Have you tried changing the url to taglib uri to https?

Comment: Yes, I did. I get Exception


org.apache.jasper.JasperException: The absolute uri: https://tiles.apache.org/tags-tiles cannot be resolved in either web.xml or the jar files deployed with this application



I don't understand where it looks for lib.

This: "One trick which might be useful is to use protocol-relative hyperlinks, of the form “//example.com/image.gif”." is the first thing i tried, it produces the same exception.